# pushing the filtered obj to an empty array in react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an  array called persons and  selectedPersons in my state both are empty array

```
state = {persons:[], selectedPersons:[]}
```

on componentnDidMount i am calling the fetchPersons method and i am storing the response in the items

after componentDidMount

```
state = {
    items: [
        {id:5,name:"test1"},
        {id:6,name:"test2"},
        {id:7,name:"test3"}
    ],
    selectedPersons:[]
}
```

clicking on each item i am calling selectedPerson method , where i am passing the id

// example

if i clicked on the 'test1' i am passing id 5 to the method and dispatching an action

// reducer

```
case actionTypes.SELECTED_PERSON:
      return{
        ...state,
        selectedPersons: state.persons.map(obj => {
          if(obj.id === action.payload.personId){
            //console.log("obj", obj);
            //console.log("selectedPersons", state.selectedPersons);
             return {...obj}
           // how can i push each item initially the selectedPersons is 
           //  empty
          }
        })
      }
```

expected output after clicking on each person

```
state = {
    items: [
        {id:5,name:"test1"},
        {id:6,name:"test2"},
        {id:7,name:"test3"}
    ],
    selectedPersons:[{id:5,name:"test1"}]
}
```

when clicking on each person i need to update the selectedPersons array without mutating

i have tried `{...state.selectedPersons, ...obj}` but yet didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work?

```
case actionTypes.SELECTED_PERSON: {
  const person = state.persons.find(p => p.id === action.payload.personId);
  return{
    ...state,
    selectedPersons: [...state.selectedPersons, person];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to push object into an array without mutating the state.
what I usually do is, I pass the selectedPerson object as payload from action creator, then you can do the following in your reducer.

```
case actionTypes.SELECTED_PERSON :
    return { 
        ...state,
        //if object doesn't already exists push it otherwise slice it
        selectedPersons: [...state.selectedPersons, action.person]
    }
```

OR

```
case actionTypes.SELECTED_PERSON :
    return { 
        ...state,
        selectedPersons: state.selectedPersons.concat(action.person)
    }
```

Working with ES6 you should use first one.